# Is there an actual iPhone App cache.db available to view just like a simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, caching, simulator

I have the following code to find the iPhone's cache.db.

```
    NSArray* paths1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* cacheDir = [paths1 objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"cache directory%@",cacheDir);
```

Which prints out this location.

> ```
> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/02DAB563-8FBC-44E2-854A-B8A1F8B90635/Library/Caches
> ```

However, I can't find the cache.db.
This is strange because I can find the cache.db for simulators, but not iPhone. Is the cache.db hidden for actual iPhone devices. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file will be on the device, not your local file system.

Comment: I found it on my device using iExplorer. However, the url requests aren't showing inside cache.db like they are on my simulator. Is this normal? I am using AFNetWorking.

Comment: I see you edited the original question. You should ask that as a separate question. A new question with a better title will get better answers.

Comment: Okay, I thought I might've got in trouble. Thank you will do.